# Mongodb async java driver find()

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous

I have a webapp in which I have to return the results from a mongodb find() to the front-end from my java back-end.
I am using the Async Java driver, and the only way I think I have to return the results from mongo is something like this:

```
public String getDocuments(){
  ...
  collection.find(query).map(Document::toJson)
        .into(new HashSet<String>(), new SingleResultCallback<HashSet<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(HashSet<String> strings, Throwable throwable) {
              // here I have to get all the Json Documents in the set,
              // make a whole json string and wake the main thread
            }
        });
  // here I have to put the main thread to wait until I get the data in
  // the onResult() method so I can return the string back to the front-end
  ...
  return jsonString;
}
```

Is this assumption right or there´s another way to do it?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use the asynchronous API as if it were the synchronous one. Is there a reason you aren't using the synchronous one in the first place?

Comment: I can´t really answer that question. I thought that it might improve mongo´s (or my app) performance even if a I use the async api in a synchronous way. Is this true? or am I wrong?

Comment: The purpose of an asynchronous API is that you can do other stuff while you wait for data to arrive or run multiple data requests in parallel. When you don't make any use of this because you always wait for data doing nothing, you are only creating additional overhead, both computationally and syntactically.

Comment: Ok, so could you give me one example of a java backend using the Async driver that is justified and worth using it?

Comment: It would be only worth for operations like insert or update?

Comment: it's definitely useful for insert and update because you can often continue program execution assuming they will be successful and revert that assumption when you get an error message through a callback later. For find-queries: one use-case is when you need to do multiple independent queries to fulfill a request. An asynchronous API allows you to run these queries in parallel instead of one after another.

Comment: Again a perfect answer! Thank you very much!!
One last question: in the case I use an asynchronous insert or update and I get an error in the callback, what would be the proper way to revert or notify the front-end? via websockets? or I should do another thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asynchronous APIs (any API based on callbacks, not necessarily MongoDB) can be a true blessing for multithreaded applications. But to really benefit from them, you need to design your whole application architecture in an asynchronous fashion. This is not always feasible, especially when it is supposed to fit into a given framework which isn't built on callbacks.

So sometimes (like in your case) you just want to use an asynchronous API in a synchronous fashion. In that case, you can use the class [`CompletableFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

This class provides (among others) two methods `<T> get()` and `complete(<T> value)`. The method `get` will block until `complete` is called to provide the return value (should `complete` get called before `get`, `get` returns immediately with the provided value).

```
public String getDocuments(){
  ...
  CompletableFuture<String> result = new CompletableFuture<>(); // <-- create an empty, uncompleted Future

  collection.find(query).map(Document::toJson)
        .into(new HashSet<String>(), new SingleResultCallback<HashSet<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(HashSet<String> strings, Throwable throwable) {
              // here I have to get all the Json Documents in the set and
              // make a whole json string

              result.complete(wholeJsonString); // <--resolves the future
            }
        });

  return result.get(); // <-- blocks until result.complete is called
}
```

The the `get()`-method of CompletableFuture also [has an alternative overload with a timeout parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). I recommend using this to prevent your program from accumulating hanging threads when the callback is not called for whatever reason. It will also be a good idea to implement your whole callback in a `try {` block and do the `result.complete` in the `finally {` block to make sure the result always gets resolved, even when there is an unexpected error during your callback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right.

That's the correct behaviour of Mongo async driver (see [MongoIterable.into](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoIterable.html#into-A-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-)).

However, Why don't you use sync driver in this situation? Is there any reason to use async method?